# How to use response cache for serverAndClient

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, middleware, asp.net-core-middleware

We are porting an asp.net MVC application to asp NET core MVC In the asp.net MVC we have for some MVC controller output cache enabled below is the code

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 900, VarByParam ="*", Location ="ServerAndClient")]
```

I am aware response cache is what should be used for outputcache in asp.net core mvc but in response cache there is no Enum value for ServerAndClient in Location enum.

So how should we approach the problem. Should we write our own middleware for this or there is a built=in way of doing it or there is a third party library which does the same.

Answer (score 1):

> So how should we approach the problem. Should we write our own
> middleware for this or there is a built=in way of doing it or there is
> a third party library which does the same.

Yes, you should use the middleware with the `UseResponseCaching`. There is no option to put the cache on the `server` in `ResponseCacheLocation`. It has been described in [ASP.NET Core documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/response?view=aspnetcore-3.1).

### Response caching in ASP.NET Core

`Response caching` reduces the number of requests a **client** or **proxy** makes to a web server. `Response caching` also reduces the amount of work the web server performs to generate a response. `Response caching` is controlled by headers that specify how you want client, proxy, and middleware to cache responses.

The ResponseCache attribute participates in setting response caching headers. **Clients** and **intermediate proxies** should honor the headers for caching responses under the HTTP 1.1 Caching specification.

**For server-side caching that follows the HTTP 1.1 Caching specification, use Response Caching Middleware. The middleware can use the `ResponseCacheAttribute` properties to influence server-side caching behavior.**

> How to configure Response Caching Middleware in ASP.NET Core

[Response Caching Middleware in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/middleware?view=aspnetcore-3.1)